# XSLT Not Rendering HTML

Tags: html, xslt

I have a XSLT document that I am trying to edit so that it will show the HTML correctly rather than showing the actual HTML tags.  Below is a snipet of part of the XSLT and the HTML.  When the page is rendered is shows the HTML tags instead of rendering them.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Sorry about the code being on one line.  I couldn't figure out how to get it to work if it was formatted on multiple lines.

```
<!-- Test Template -->
<xsl:template match="TestTemplate">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font
                    style='font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px; color:#c41130'>
                    <b>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Title" />
                    </b>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">
                <font style="color:#333333">
                    <b>Title</b>
                </font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font style="color:#333333">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Title" />
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">
                <font style="color:#333333">
                    <b>Department</b>
                </font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font style="color:#333333">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Department" />
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">
                <font style="color:#333333">
                    <b>Type</b>
                </font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font style="color:#333333">
                    <xsl:value-of select="JobType" />
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="line">
                <img src="/img/s.gif" height="1" width="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="/img/s.gif" height="5" width="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <xsl:if test="(Description)">
        <br />
        <font
            style='font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px; color:#c41130'>
            <b>Description</b>
        </font>
        <br />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Description/Line" />
        <br />
    </xsl:if>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
```

Test HTML that is showing the html tags instead of rendering them.

```
<b>TEST HEADING</b>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    This should be a list.
</li>
    <li>This should be a list.</li>
    <li>This should be a list.</li>
    <li>This should be a list.</li>
    <li>This should be a list.</li>
    <li>This should be a list.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire XSLT? (The whole `xsl:stylesheet`.)

Comment: Please also format the XSL to be legible on more than one line.

Comment: @Kevin - Just wait until I finish my Greasemonkey script for pretty-printing XML in a `<textarea>` with `ctrl-shift-f` :)

Comment: @bsmith95610: The elements you are trying to match/select (`TestTemplate`, `Description`, `Line`, `JobType`, `Department` and `Title`) have nothing to do with your "Test HTML" (?!) ...

Answer (score 3):

Where are you attempting to transform/display your input/output? In a browser? The default output method for XSLT is XML, but you can specify HTML with the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <!-- other XSLT goes here -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In, Firefox, for example, this results in a rendering of the output as a webpage.

Comment: Every browser will correctly display XHTML coming from an XSLT transformation (XML with PI, do not attempt this through javascript...): modern browsers as long as you correctly declare the XHTML namespace, IE just because it tries hard to think that everything is HTML...

Comment: lwburk - I am trying to display it in a browser.  I already have those tags at the top of my xslt file.

Comment: The text is showing up like so <b>ESSENTIAL DUTIES:</b> when I pull it from my database.  If I wrap it in a font tag and change the color when it renders out it does change the color but it wouldn't bold the text it just writes it like the above.

Comment: @bsmith95610 - Can you update with a more complete example? The XSL above appears to have nothing to do with your Test HTML output, which is confusing.